# ANN for decompiler?

Tags: reverse-engineering, neural-network, decompiler

Has there ever been any attempts at utilizing artificial neural networks in decompilation? It would be nice if it was possible to provide the trimmed semantics of source along with the code in to a neural network so it could learn the connection between the two. I assume this would likely lose it's effectiveness when there is optimizations and maybe work better for high level languages too but I'm interested in hearing any attempts anyone has had at this.

Comment: Having worked in decompilers, I think this is a lot harder than you think. Changing the address of a jump instruction by 1 byte can drastically alter control flow. Therefore some sort of means of abstracting this above assembly language is needed. And then you go down the road of basically writing large parts of the decompiler. Another aspect: who is going to pay for the work that needs to be done? Writing a good decompiler is easly a full time job for one person. Tasks include keeping up to date with compiler/optimization/assembly changes, and testing frameworks. Hey, why don't you try it?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  https://www.groundai.com/project/a-neural-based-program-decompiler/1

Answer (score 1):

I added this as a comment, but I think I will go ahead and post it as an answer as well.  It looks like in the 11 years sense this question has been posted, there has been work done in this direction.  Here is a link:
https://www.groundai.com/project/a-neural-based-program-decompiler/1

And here is the abstract

### A Neural-based Program Decompiler

> Reverse engineering of binary executables is a critical problem in the computer security domain. On the one hand, malicious parties may recover interpretable source codes from the software products to gain commercial advantages. On the other hand, binary decompilation can be leveraged for code vulnerability analysis and malware detection. However, efficient binary decompilation is challenging. Conventional decompilers have the following major limitations: (i) they are only applicable to specific source-target language pair, hence incurs undesired development cost for new language tasks; (ii) their output high-level code cannot effectively preserve the correct functionality of the input binary; (iii) their output program does not capture the semantics of the input and the reversed program is hard to interpret. To address the above problems, we propose Coda111Coda is the abbreviation for CodeAttack., the first end-to-end neural-based framework for code decompilation. Coda decomposes the decompilation task into of two key phases: First, Coda employs an instruction type-aware encoder and a tree decoder for generating an abstract syntax tree (AST) with attention feeding during the code sketch generation stage. Second, Coda then updates the code sketch using an iterative error correction machine guided by an ensembled neural error predictor. By finding a good approximate candidate and then fixing it towards perfect, Coda achieves superior performance compared to baseline approaches. We assess Coda’s performance with extensive experiments on various benchmarks. Evaluation results show that Coda achieves an average of 82% program recovery accuracy on unseen binary samples, where the state-of-the-art decompilers yield 0% accuracy. Furthermore, Coda outperforms the sequence-to-sequence model with attention by a margin of 70% program accuracy. Our work reveals the vulnerability of binary executables and imposes a new threat to the protection of Intellectual Property (IP) for software development.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean decompilation to human readable C/C++ as compared to Assembly then,

Given the input size (optimized/compiled code) and the output size of succinct code, and the multi-line stateful nature of decomplilation process,  I would have though this is a larger problem that a ANN could ever handle.

Comment: Yes human readble but not necessarily C/C++, if ever such a project was started C/C++ may be the last choice. I did say I would provide trimmed semantics (not original formatted source) and unoptimized code to the ANN.

Comment: why not C? it can express everything (mostly) that can be done else where. And therefore re-compiled to functionally equivalent executable. Or are you meaning using some other language as the source, and therefore there you could only decode a sub-set of executables.

Comment: Your misunderstanding I don't dislike C. High level languages that are stored in byte codes and vm assembly would be a more suitable choice than machine assembly code.

Comment: true, you never mentioned your target binary.