# how to decompile the source code of a mac app?

Tags: macos, reverse-engineering, gpgpu, decompiler, binaries

for matters of personal study of specific commercial applications source code, in order to build my own (not stealing the source code, but Just figuring out how things are actually done), i intend to decompile mac OS X binaries, and get their source. i need an intelligent decompiler, preferably GPGPU based, which can get me the source code of the app by trying to guess the language it was written in, and dumping out a code that is preferably as far as possible from the original app. kind regards. and best wishes. Tiago

Comment: Nevertheless, one could interpret it as problematic towards intellectual property...

Comment: like i say, i have an ethical understanding towards the implications of technology usage, and this case EULAs, and these kinds of things, and i don't meant to re-distribute any source, or application made with these kinds of things. it's Just for personal study, on the exact same way i would study source code downloaded from a github repository. when you have tools for accomplishing specific stuff, it's your own ethical, moral and deontological responsibility to use them on a proper way.

Comment: agreed, I was just making my point: "one could..." and maybe some tech companies do understand it that way... - consider it as a reminder on the aforementioned issues.

Comment: also it would be nice to have some for of artificial intelligence involved. i saw this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000994/ann-for-decompiler?rq=1, but they don't give an answer based on an existing tool based on these pre-assumptions

Comment: i know about hopper. but hopper decompiles for assembly. is there any tool that can decompile for an higher level scripting language such as c or c++, or even the program's original language (better for paradigm coherence of the scripting result)

Comment: What about IDA Pro? https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/6.8/index.shtml especialy their comment about objective-c in the 6.2. release notes https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/6.2/index.shtml

Comment: There is no shortcut on building software. IDA Pro and Hopper are the best on the market as far as I know. There is no such think that generates Obj-C code at the moment. I only know about C code : In Czech republic there is a project with stunning results http://decompiler.fit.vutbr.cz But this is still University and research project.

Comment: thanks everyone for the precious insights. i will give a try to all of those. some really amazing stuff in terms of software engineering have been coming up from eastern europe, with the democratization of the access to tech. i am curious about the decompiler.fit.vutbr.cz, but also ida pro and hopper. i will try to fool around a bit with all of them. thanks, guys